# Can we define property of Mongoose schema model as another model

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I was creating models for my application using mongoose,
Basically when creating 2 models like this.

```
// user.js

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var user = new Schema({
  $key: String,

  us_first: String,
  us_family: String,
  displayName: String,
  email: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', user);



// project.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var project = new Schema({
  $key: String,
  project_creator: String,

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('project', project);
```

Now what i want is in the `project` model, the type of `project_creator` should be the `user` model ( right now its just a string type ).

I'm asking this because when i doing frontend using Angular and Typescript, i can declare the project model as something like this :

```
// user.ts
export class User {
    $key: string;    
    us_first: string;
    us_family: string;
    displayName: string;
    email: string;

// project.ts
export class Project {
  $key: string;
  project_creator: User;
```

So i wonder if I can declare the samething in mongoose

Comment: Have you tried `project_creator: user` ? And `module.exports` overrides the previously exported things so it makes little sense to use it twice.

Comment: have you considered using population in mongoose?  Link : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## you can try this way:

## More specific explanation is here:http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

```
export class Project {
  $key: string;
  project_creator:  {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
}
```